# How to replace an image of CCSprite with a UIImage in spritebuilder/cocos2d v3

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

CCTexture2D and CCTextureCached do not seem to work. What is the best way to replace an image of a CCSprite(created from spritbuilder) with a UIImage(an image taken from the camera)?

Comment: create a CGImage from the UIImage then init a sprite with that

Comment: I did that but it still displays the old image that was present when I created it on spritebuilder.

Comment: I want to keep the same sprite not replace it

Comment: you can also change the texture of the existing sprite

Comment: This is my code for it 
 NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
_hero = [[CCSprite alloc]initWithCGImage:image.CGImage key:nil];
but it still does not work

Comment: the texture may still be cached, use cctexturecaxhe remove message with @"image" as the key

Comment: It says cctexturecache is undeclared... 
I tried this CCTexture *tex = [[CCTexture alloc]initWithCGImage:image.CGImage contentScale:40];
and then
 [_hero setTexture:tex];
but I cannot see the image again

Comment: Instead of "contentScale:40" try "contentScale:1".

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. The old image of the CCSprite is still present and I can't see the new Image

Comment: from the top of my head: [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTextureForKey:@"image"];
Allow Xcode autocomplete to help you with available "remove" methods or look into the class' header file (@interface)

Comment: Isn't CCTextureCache gone for Cocos2d v3?